# tessellation in 3 dimensions with R

Tags: r, 3d, tessellation

I have a set of 3D points (space (x,y) and time t) and I want to construct a quadrature using if possible the Dirichlet tessellation and most important, compute the quadrature weights, meaning the volume of the Dirichlet 3 dimensional 'tiles'. All of this in R. I found the geometry package but it doesn't compute the volumes. Do you know any R packages that could help me with this?

---

Here is the code:

```
library(geometry) 
library(rgl) 
library(scatterplot3d)
x <- runif(20, 0, 1) 
y <- runif(20, 0, 1) 
z <- runif(20, 0, 1)
d <- cbind(x, y, z) 
scatterplot3d::scatterplot3d(d) 
t <- delaunayn(d)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: This is what I have for now:
`library(geometry)
library(rgl)

x<-runif(20,0,1)
y<-runif(20,0,1)
z<-runif(20,0,1)
d<-cbind(x,y,z)

scatterplot3d::scatterplot3d(d)

t<-delaunayn(d)
`

Comment: If you call `geometry::delaunayn` now (version >= 0.4.4) with `output.options = "Fa"` it returns an output list with the vector `$areas`. The documentation of this vector says `an M-dimensional vector containing the generalised area of each simplex (e.g. in 2D the areas of triangles; in 3D the volumes of tetrahedra)`. If I get this correctly, then that's what @A.Iftimi was searching for.